# How can I get result as 0 if IN() condition value not exist in the table

Tags: mysql, sql

My table is:

```
s_no  user  join_year  knowledge handled_pojects_count
1     john     2017    PHP        5
2     john     2017    SQL        5
3     gokul    2017    JAVA       3
4     gokul    2017    PHP        2
5     hari     2017    ASP        1
6     hari     2017    Azure      9
```

Below one is my query

```
SELECT 
COALESCE(SUM(handled_pojects_count),0) AS count,
knowledge
FROM team_members WHERE
join_year = '2017' AND 
user = 'john' AND 
knowledge IN ('PHP','JAVA');
```

I need the result that should have both values for knowledge like below

```
    project count
    PHP     5
    JAVA    0
```

How can I arrive this?

Comment: can you please format properly. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
SELECT 
knowledge,
SUM(CASE WHEN join_year = 2017 AND user = 'john' THEN ISNULL(handled_projects_count,0) ELSE 0 END) as cnt
FROM team_members WHERE
knowledge IN ('PHP','JAVA')
GROUP BY knowledge
```

Comment: This gives 0 if the result row is 0. 
But if rows exist, it gives just 1 instead of actual count.

Comment: Can you add your sample data? @user2902011

Comment: Hi @Bennjoe, Added the data in question

Comment: Please see updated code. @user2902011 I thought you were just counting the occurrence of the row

Answer (score 0):

below one working fine.
Thanks for your help!

```
SELECT 
knowledge,
SUM(CASE WHEN join_year = 2017 AND user = 'john' THEN handled_pojects_count ELSE 0 END) as cnt
FROM team_members WHERE
knowledge IN ('PHP','JAVA')
GROUP BY knowledge
```